# Mailchimp Automation Schedule - Send on Specific Days only

Tags: mailchimp

I'm setting up a date-based automation within Mailchimp, and want to ensure that the email is sent only on a given day of the week. I believe I have it configure correctly, however the email is sent as soon as the trigger is reached.

Essentially, my situation is as follows:

- When a subscriber joins the mailing list, they enter a specific date (e.g. 1st July 2017)
- When this date is reached, I want to send them an email the following Tuesday. (1st July 2017 is on a Saturday, I want to email them on the Tuesday)

I have setup a Mailchimp automation with the following settings:

- Workflow Recipe: Specific Date
- Email Trigger: "On the day of"
- Email Schedule: Tuesday, 8pm

The schedule is shown in the screenshot:
[Email Schedule Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsccD.png)

As the screenshot states setting a schedule can delay the send, which is exactly what I want. However, the email is sent out the day the trigger is hit, but at the 8pm time. (for my above example, the email would be received on the Saturday @ 8pm). As I understand it, this should not be happening as the email *should* only send on Tuesdays.

I have a series of emails setup in this automation, all based on the same logic but with different triggers (on the day of, one week after, one month after, etc)

Is there anything in addition to this I need to setup?

I should note that I'm on a *forever free* account, if that has any limitations.

Comment: wild guess. The user might be present in multiple campaigns and one of which triggers on Saturday. Not exactly sure the meaning of "However, the email is sent out the day the trigger is hit". What is the trigger condition here? Joining the list?

Comment: Hi Sameer. The trigger condition is "the day of the date field". So in my example above, the date field has "1st July 2017" in it, and the trigger should fire on that day, but not send until the Tuesday. I don't think it's another campaign firing. I've isolated my problem as much as I can; a test list with one subscriber, and a single automation on that list.